# Basic understanding Hbase Filters

Tags: hbase

I have a table with the following row keys (shortened for sake of the example):

```
s1-0                                                
s1-1                                                 
s1-2                             
s2-0                            
s2-1                          
s3-0
```

I need to filter rows in these ways:

- all rows where the first part is s1 and the second part  is < 2
- all rows where the first part is s1 and the second part is in the range 1 - 2
- all rows where the second part is in the range 1 - 2

I started with basic filtering. If I scan the table with this filter:

```
Filter f  = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator("s1-2"));
```

I get only the row with:

```
s1-2
```

But if I change the filter to:

```
Filter f  = new RowFilter(CompareOp.LESS, new RegexStringComparator("s1-2"));
```

my expectation is to get:

```
s1-0                                                
s1-1
```

instead I get:

```
s1-0: 0
s1-1: 1
s2-0: 0
s2-1: 1
s3-0: 0
```

I am missing something important in understanding how filters work. Can anyone help me and provide some usefull documentation reference on filters?

Answer (score 0):

In a book I came across this:

> the BitComparator, RegexStringComparator, and SubstringComparator  only work with the EQUAL and NOT_EQUAL operators, as the compareTo() of these comparators return 0 for a match and 1 when there is no match. **Using them in a LESS or GREATER comparison will yield erroneous results**.